# Serial port logging tool

Tags: logging, serial-port

I have a device that has an occasional failure. Once every few days. The device has a serial port for debugging. And outputs lots of lines.

Is there a tool that can I use to record the output of the debug stream to a file per hour, while prefixing a timestamp?

I know I can just put an rpi there with a simple `screen tty > file` but that would create a huge un-timestamped file no viewer can open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some python code named [Grabserial](http://elinux.org/Grabserial) that, in combination with some scripting, does what I'm after.

[Github](https://github.com/tbird20d/grabserial).